# Enabling a button on enterng a minimum of 6 numbers

Tags: jquery, regex, html

I have a text box and a button, and I want to validate the text box to enter only numbers. Once the entered numbers reaches a count of six I need to enable my button. The maximum count I am handling by using maxLength in html.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#txt").keyup(function () {
            var text = $(this).val();
            var maxLength=6;
            var textLength = text.length;
            if (textLength >= maxLength) {
              $('#btn').show();
            }
         else
         {
              $('#btn').hide();
         }
        });
```

**Demo with Show/Hide button:**

http://jsfiddle.net/R66Wn/1/

**Updated Demo with Enable/Disable button:**

http://jsfiddle.net/R66Wn/2/

Answer (score 0):

Assign an event for your textbox, that checks for that minimum value.

Depending on that value, change the `disabled` prop using jquery.

Here's a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g4J59/2/)

Here's the HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="num" />

<button id="myButton" disabled>My Button</button>
```

Here's the jQuery code:

```
jQuery('#num').keyup(function () { 
    var minLength = 6;
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');

    if ($(this).val().length >= minLength)
    {

        $('#myButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should post the code of the fiddle as well, so in case the fiddle gets deleted some day the code is still available to readers.